# ISA relationship

Tags: sql-server, relations

[image]

How do I model this ISA when designing tables for the database ? (You may add meaningful attributes if it will enhance your explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've drawn the diagram, it would mean that you want the "product" to be able to be e.g. both a "mobile" and a "tablet". If you want that, you'd need a foreign key in product pointing to the primary key of the other three tables, and insert a NULL when it isn't one of them.

In everyday language, you can say "this product is a tablet". But in this context, it's likely that you really want the three entities on the right to be all products; and therefore, you just add a product_id column to each of these that points to the id column of product. In the product table, you keep track of generic information, like who's the manufacturer, the price, etc. In the tables on the right of your diagram, you add specialized information that makes sense only for them, e.g. for a mobile, whether it supports 4G, which is not applicable to an accessory.